# Parsing json that has unneeded fields with Moshi

Tags: android, json, kotlin, moshi

Probably a stupid question, but what is the most efficient way for Moshi to parse json which contains the fields I won't use?

For example

```
{
  "name": "Edward",
  "surname":"Elric",
  "height": 165
}
```

and I won't use a "height" inside an app.

Should I create a data class with all 3 fields and mark "height" @Json(ignore = true) or @Transcient?

Or should I just create a data class with 2 fields?

Which is more efficient and proper way?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need propery high at all, it is more efficient to create a class with 2 properties only - name and surname. The instance will take less memory